# Laravel Websocket event subscribing but not firing message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-websockets

I have configured laravel websockets into my project. I can run websockets successfully event are getting subscribed when I am trying to send message its not going through. I tried even tinker `event (new \App\Events\NewTrade('Hi there'))` I can't see any output neither in console nore in dashboard.

Please help me to fix or debug.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading `laravel-php-server` from `7.2.1` to `7.0.2` everything started working fine.